# how to design a table in android

Tags: android, android-layout

in my app i need to design like the following image [image]

i use table layout for this but i get like follwing:

TextViewTextViewTextView
.....

mycode:

```
   ....... 
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Your State"
       android:layout_gravity="left" android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Your State"
       android:layout_gravity="left" android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
     .........
```

my design is not shown as above image. i do not know how to design exact the above image. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have six tablerows intable layout and each tablerow whould consists of four textviews.

### See the Sample Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pas111"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pas111"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pas111"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pas111"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pas111"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
     android:layout_weight="0.2"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Save As..."
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
     android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="Ctrl-Oda asd dfgd df gdfgd gdf dfg dfgd df g  d a asda dsadasd ada das sad adas  das dsa dsda asd asd  sad a dad" />


</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

======================

drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="8dp"
    android:top="8dp"
    android:right="8dp"
    android:bottom="8dp" />
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF0000"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

try experimenting with "android:stretchColumns"

Answer (score 0):

```
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default_small"
```

put this tag in textViews and tableLayout u have.. in xml.. u cantry giving other values like `"editbox_background"` etc..

Comment: i use your code. if i give long text as shown in the image it does not appear in multi lines although  give the following             android:maxLines="3"
android:text="Without Swimming pool cover". how to get long text in multi lines

Comment: set android:singleline="false"

Comment: android:singleLine="false" it does not work. still  appear in single line so that other textviews are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Make Table using HTML/CSS. The table would be made easily and much more beautiful. Use WebView to access the HTML file of table. Save html file in the assets folder.
For more details google how to implement HTML file in Android.