# How to create a table with dynamic rows in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am  new at android, I am stuck with the following puzzle.

I need to create a table in Android which looks the following:

Category  | Item Name |  Marks Obtained | Max Marks|

---

Row 1 information

---

Row2 information

---

The problem  that I am facing is that these rows need to be created on the  fly depending on the number of items.
I have looked around and found table layout information which is very generic or does not show how to create dynamic tables.

P.S. I cannot attach the exact picture of the table because I don't have enough points

Answer (score 0):

you create this. First create a table. Now you came to know the number of rows that you want to create(dynamically).

```
    private TableLayout myTableLay;
    private TableRow demoTableRow[];
    private String cat[],itemName[],marks[],maxMarks[];    
    private int count;
        public void example()
    {
      myTableLay = new TableLayout(this);
      myTableLay.removeAllViews();
      myTableLay.refreshDrawableState();

     // i hope now you got count.
      demoTableRow = new TableRow[count];
      cat = new String[count];
      itemName= new String[count];
      marks= new String[count];
      maxMarks= new String[count];

     for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      {
         // add all inforamation to your tablerow in such a maaner that you want to display on screen.


     myTableLay.addView(demoTableRow[i);
       }
 //hope it might helpful.
    }
```

Comment: but what about the xml file for creating the ui for the table ? how do i include that information ?

Comment: in xml file add scrollview at last & add table into scrollview so that it will be scrolled also.

Comment: so I should create a table view with a single table row and use the sample code provided in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435553/how-to-design-a-table-in-andriod)